# FFMpeg Alsa: Understanding hw:#,#,#

Tags: sound, alsa, ffmpeg

I have seen somewhere when we need to capture audio from Alsa in FFMPEG screen capture, we specify the hardware `hw:`, for eg, `hw:0,1,0`. From the official doc, I understand `hw:X,Y` [see here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/ALSA)
Can someone explain the significance of the third argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third number is the subdevice number, and might be useful only for sound cards that implement hardware mixing. (If you leave the third number out, ALSA chooses the first free one, which is what you want in most cases.)

There are no cards that have multiple subdevices on a capture device, so specifying it is pointless (it's always zero).